# How to attach mail with UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

The current solution is i need to save image and then load attachment with file
is it possible to load from UIImageView directly?
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment is set as a NSData object and you can get it from UIImage object directly using one of the following functions:

- `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` - for image in JPEG format
- `UIImagePNGRepresentation` - for image in PNG format

Comment: if i want to load from uiimaveview is it possible? i dont know solution for load uiimageview to uiimage.

Comment: yes, get an image from imageview and pass it to functions I mention to get image data. SOmething like this: NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);

Comment: [mail addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"" fileName:@""]; in mimeType and fileName what should i insert to in because i grab from UIImageView i dont know  the mimeType and not have filename

Comment: mimetype - image/png or image/jpeg depending on what format you use. For file name you can set arbitrary name - I suppose user will see it as an attachment name when he receives email